# How to monitor questions for answers?

Tags: discussion

I am really struggling with this one...

Given a user ID, how can I monitor questions that that user has asked for new answers?

I'm worried the solution will look something like this:

- Get all questions for a given user
- Get answer_count for each of them
- Compare each answer_count to the stored number from the last check
- If any two don't match, then an answer has been added or deleted
- Repeat at specified interval

Is there a better way?
Is there some way to get all answers posted to a user's questions between a given time span?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sort=creation` and `min` to pull in only new answers given a list of question ids and the [`questions/{id}/answer`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/questions/1/answers?help) route.

You can do the equivalent with [`users/{id}/questions`](http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.9/users/1/questions?help) to monitor for new questions.

That will let you monitor up to 100 questions a request.

Comment: Kevin: I'm a bit surprised by this, and I have to think it's intentional. Wouldn't one of the MOST COMMON API REQUESTS be "get me all new answers to any of my questions?". I imagine, however, that if a proliferation of notifiers appeared, people would check the sites less, and the community would suffer.

Comment: Links not working.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an API request every few minutes and parse it out then compare it.  That's the only way I can think of.  Sure it'll be a lot of code, but you gotta do what you gotta do

Answer (score 1):

I think polling with  `/users/{id}/questions` is the best option here. I don't think you have to compare the answer_counts though. You could try the `fromdate` param on the api call, and just save the time of the last request. Then anything in the response must be after that time and therefore new.

Comment: Does `fromdate` only return questions with new answers? Otherwise it won't work.